# I'm trying to rig my character but for some reason it acts weirdly

Tags: modeling, rigging, weight-painting

So I have created my first character and now I want to rig it, I have tried doing it with the rigify addon and without it as well but both times it acts weirdly. I even try to manually weight paint it but nothing weight paints for some reason. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJv-weahqqc) is a video of me trying to rig it with the rigify addon:

Comment: Hello could you please share your object with its armature? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: For some reason the files are not uploading

Comment: you need to copy paste the url of this page to be able to upload, or use another platform like workupload

Comment: Could you please share the armature as well? Or maybe just try to recalculate the normals of your mesh (select all in Edit mode and Shift N) and reparent to see if it works

Comment: For some reason now it is saying when I parent the armature and the mesh "Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have flipped normals and overlapping vertices. To fix that, in *Edit* mode select all and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> and also <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*.